# How to set width to SimplePolylineGeometry primitive in CesiumJS

Tags: cesiumjs

I have this code, which adds polyline primitive to scene.

```
function createPolyline(startPosition, endPosition) {
        Cesium.SimplePolylineGeometry({
            positions : [startPosition, endPosition]
        });

        var geometry = Cesium.SimplePolylineGeometry.createGeometry(polyline);
        return scene.primitives.add(new Cesium.Primitive({
            geometryInstances : new Cesium.GeometryInstance({
                geometry   : geometry,
                attributes : {
                    color : Cesium.ColorGeometryInstanceAttribute.fromColor(Cesium.Color.SPRINGGREEN)
                }
            }),
            appearance        : new Cesium.PerInstanceColorAppearance()
        }));
    }
```

How do I set width of this polyline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended way to add a polyline is with the Entity API, [like this](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Polyline.html&label=Showcases)

```
var greenLine = viewer.entities.add({
    polyline : {
        positions : [startPosition, endPosition],
        width : 5,
        material : Cesium.Color.SPRINGGREEN
    }
});
```

But, if you want to skip the Entity layer and use the Primitive Graphics layer directly, you can do that too.  Your sample code above has some issues.  First, you're calling the `Cesium.SimplePolylineGeometry` constructor without the `new` keyword, and without saving the result, and this is not the correct use pattern for this kind of code.  Second, the `SimplePolylineGeometry` class itself does not support line widths greater than what the WebGL implementation supports, which on Windows machines running ANGLE, is only 1 pixel wide.  To get around this limitation, use the normal (non-simple) polylines, like this:

```
var polylines = scene.primitives.add(new Cesium.PolylineCollection());
var polyline = polylines.add({
    positions : Cesium.PolylinePipeline.generateCartesianArc({
        positions : [startPosition, endPosition]
    }),
    material : Cesium.Material.fromType('Color', {
        color : Cesium.Color.SPRINGGREEN
    }),
    width: 5
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`SimplePolylineGeometry` does not support line width.  You need to use `PolylineGeometry` instead and pass the "width" options to the constructor.  Also, you should be using `PolylineColorAppearance` as your `appearance`, not `PerInstanceColorAppearance`.